# Why my regular expression does not work in JavaScript? (It works in Java)

Tags: javascript, java, regex

The regular expression is "`(\d+)|(N\A)`", which matches digits or string "N\A". It works in Java, but not in JavaScript.

1. Results are different between Java and JavaScript.
2. Results of two versions in JavaScript are different.

What's wrong I made?

Code code snippet:

**Java**

Environment: JDK 1.8.0_144

```
String orderNumberRegExp = "(\\d+)|(N/A)";
System.out.println("12345".matches(orderNumberRegExp));

String digitalOnly = "\\d+";
System.out.println("12345".matches(digitalOnly));
System.out.println("12345ABC".matches(digitalOnly));
```

Output (as my expected):

```
true
true
false
```

**JavaScript**

Environment: node v9.8.0

The two versions return wrong results both.

Version 1:

```
var orderNumberRegExp = new RegExp("(\d+)|(N\/A)"); // or "(\d+)|(N/A)"
console.log(orderNumberRegExp.test("12345"));

var digitalOnly = new RegExp("\d+");
console.log(digitalOnly.test("12345"));
console.log(digitalOnly.test("12345ABC"));
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
```

Version 2:

```
var orderNumberRegExp = /(\d+)|(N\/A)/
console.log(orderNumberRegExp.test("12345"));

var digitalOnly = /\d+/;
console.log(digitalOnly.test("12345"));
console.log(digitalOnly.test("12345ABC"));
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
```

---

Thanks for all your help. My code has issues:

1. When to create regular expression using `RegExp()`, the backslash should be escaped. (@LukStorms, @grzegorz-oledzki, and @benny)
   (Also Ref to the demo from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
2. The test method is different from the matches method in Java. It should add `^` and `$` to assert the start and end of the string. (More details in the answer by @sweeper )

So, code can be:

```
var orderNumberRegExp = new RegExp("^(\\d+)$|^(N/A)$");
console.log(orderNumberRegExp.test("12345")); // true
console.log(orderNumberRegExp.test("N/A")); // true
console.log(orderNumberRegExp.test("12345ABC")); // false
console.log(orderNumberRegExp.test("ABC1234")); // false

var digitalOnly = new RegExp("^\\d+$");
console.log(digitalOnly.test("12345")); // true
console.log(digitalOnly.test("12345ABC")); // false
```

The regular expressions can also be:

```
var orderNumberRegExp = /^(\d+)$|^(N\/A)$/
var digitalOnly = /^\d+$/
```

Comment: Why didn't you double-backslash in the javascript version 1?

Comment: var digitalOnly = /\d+$/;  try this

Comment: It's about `\d`. I cannot explain it, but if you replace it with `[0-9]` - it works as expected.

Comment: If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @LukStorms, yes, you are right. In the version 1, we have to use double-backslash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `test` method is different from the `matches` method in Java.

[`RegEx.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns true whenever a match is found in the string, whereas [`Matcher.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) returns true only if the whole string matches the pattern. So the JavaScript `test()` is more similar to the Java [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) than to `Matcher.matches()`.

To make your Javascript regexes work, you need to add `^` and `$` to assert the start and end of the string:

```js
    var orderNumberRegExp = /^(?:(\d+)|(N\/A))$/
    console.log(orderNumberRegExp.test("12345"));
    
    var digitalOnly = /^\d+$/;
    console.log(digitalOnly.test("12345"));
    console.log(digitalOnly.test("12345ABC"));
```

This will simulate the behaviour of `Matcher.matches()`

Comment: Nice answer with great explanations +1! (I took the freedom to add the code snippet) sorry for that ;-)

Comment: This `^(\d+)|(N\/A)$` should be this `^(?:(\d+)|(N\/A))$`. And you didn't mention why RegExp returned false for all input strings which I think is the first issue with his code.

Answer (score 2):

Try `var digitalOnly = new RegExp("\\d+");`

Comment: Sorry @Benny not to choose your answer, however, yours is correct!

Comment: @IridiumCao my answer was a quick fix. @Sweeper’s explanation is thorough and correct. You made the right choice 